# How to get all the checkbox values in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a problem in retrieving certain checkbox value: in case of radiator flush and transmission flush, by using foreach loop, I can only retrieve and display radiator's value.

Here's the HTML part

```
         <input type="checkbox" name="radiator" value="30.00">
            Radiator Flush ($30.00)<p/>
         <input type="checkbox" name="transmission" value="80.00">
         Transmission Flush ($80.00)<p/>
```

Here's php part

```
>$radiator=$_POST['radiator'];     $transmission=$_POST['transmission'];
$flushes=array($radiator,$transmission);
function cal_Flushes(){
   global $arr,$flushes,$price,
   $transmission,$radiator;
   $flushes=get_defined_vars();

   $price=0;    $selected=0;
   if(isset($flushes)){
      foreach($flushes as $val){
        if(isset($radiator)){
            return $price='30';
        }elseif(isset($transmission)){
            return $price='80';
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
      }
      return $price='110';
   }else{
      return 0;
   }
   return $price;

}
```

I checked transmission checkbox, the output value become 0.

Comment: is your `checkbox` in `<form>` tag?

Comment: yes it is in form tag otherwise, it won't read a value

Comment: thats what i meant..could you post a bit more code related to it?the function and where you passed the value